# Good test accuracy but poor confusion matrix results

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, classification, keras

Ive trained a model to classify 4 types of eye diseases using MobileNet as the pretrained model. I achieved a test accuracy of 94%, but when I look at the confusion matrix, it seems like it isn't doing so well. Loss is relatively low on training, validation, and testing. Any suggestions on where I went wrong or if im missing something conceptually?

```
Image_height = 224
Image_width = 224
val_split = 0.20
batches_size = 16
lr = 0.0005
spe = 220
vs = 32
epoch = 6

# Getting the file of the training set and testing set
train_folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/Research/train"
test_folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/Research/test"



#Creating batches
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input,validation_split=val_split) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_folder, target_size=(Image_height,Image_width), classes=['CNV','DME','DRUSEN','NORMAL'], batch_size=batches_size,class_mode="categorical",
                              subset="training")
validation_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input,validation_split=val_split) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_folder, target_size=(Image_height,Image_width), classes=['CNV','DME','DRUSEN','NORMAL'], batch_size=batches_size,class_mode="categorical",
                              subset="validation")
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input) \
                       .flow_from_directory(test_folder, target_size=(Image_height,Image_width), 
                         classes=['CNV','DME','DRUSEN','NORMAL'], batch_size=batches_size,class_mode="categorical")



mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(include_top=False,
                                                           input_shape=(224, 224,3),
                                                           pooling='max', weights='imagenet',
                                                           alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1,dropout=.5)
x=mobile.layers[-1].output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
predictions=Dense (4, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=predictions)    
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=True
model.compile(Adamax(lr=lr), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
checkpoint=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/content/drive/My Drive/Research/ModelCheckpoint", monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch', options=None)
lr_adjust=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1, verbose=0, mode="auto",
    min_delta=0.00001,  cooldown=0,  min_lr=0) 
callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_adjust]


model.fit(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=spe,
                    validation_data=validation_batches,validation_steps=vs, epochs=epoch)

# Predict the accuracy on the Test set
acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_batches, steps=len(test_batches), verbose=1)
print("Model Accuracy on Test Data", acc[1]*100)


y = []
for x in range(0,len(test_batches)):
  for i in range(0,len(test_batches[x][1])):
    #print(test_batches[0][1][i])
    y.append(np.argmax(test_batches[x][1][i]))
print(len(y))

con_mat = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=y, predictions=np.argmax(predictions,axis=1)).numpy()
print(con_mat)
```

**Training/Validation**

```
Epoch 1/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2952s 13s/step - loss: 0.5842 - accuracy: 0.7912 - val_loss: 0.7926 - val_accuracy: 0.7988
Epoch 2/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2736s 12s/step - loss: 0.4041 - accuracy: 0.8723 - val_loss: 0.3094 - val_accuracy: 0.9023
Epoch 3/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2635s 12s/step - loss: 0.3718 - accuracy: 0.8804 - val_loss: 0.3871 - val_accuracy: 0.8906
Epoch 4/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2517s 11s/step - loss: 0.2904 - accuracy: 0.8980 - val_loss: 0.2863 - val_accuracy: 0.9160
Epoch 5/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2364s 11s/step - loss: 0.2779 - accuracy: 0.9057 - val_loss: 0.3500 - val_accuracy: 0.9238
Epoch 6/6
220/220 [==============================] - 2241s 10s/step - loss: 0.2839 - accuracy: 0.9068 - val_loss: 0.2202 - val_accuracy: 0.9355
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f6f8a59eb70>
```

**Testing**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-12-d213edec98d3>:2: Model.evaluate_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.evaluate, which supports generators.
63/63 [==============================] - 837s 13s/step - loss: 0.1519 - accuracy: 0.9410
Model Accuracy on Test Data 94.0999984741211
```

**Confusion Matrix**

```
[[70 62 57 61]
 [82 61 41 66]
 [74 69 49 58]
 [77 60 48 65]]
```

Comment: Should be a bug in the code. If your confusion matrix is correct you should have an accuracy of the sum of the diagonal of the confusion matrix divided by the sum of all it's entries.

Comment: Have you checked your outputs? Does each row sum to 1?

Comment: @TimvonKänel Just checked, all of the outputs for each row sum to 1

Comment: I actually think your confusion matrix is just wrong. Have you checked if the amount of elements in the matrix equals your test_set size?

Comment: You have only 220 Train and 63 Test data but your confusion matrix has so many numbers ~1000. Please check the code of your confusion matrix

Comment: @TimvonKänel Yup the number of elements in the confusion matrix equals 1000. My test batch has a total of 1000 images as well

Comment: @10xAI I set it to 220 steps per epoch because im using google colab. The 63 for test data is the steps I believe (1000 images for test batch / batches of 16  -> 63)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` shuffle argument is True by default, so you must set it False and get the data in alphanumeric order. This causes consistent label assignment to images and also because of data is totally unseen in training phase it won't causes any issue on generalization of model.

```py
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(
    test_folder,
    target_size=(Image_height, Image_width),
    classes=['CNV', 'DME', 'DRUSEN', 'NORMAL'],
    batch_size=batches_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False  # here is the change 
)
```

Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58590097/10321531)

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in Tensorflow, but you pass the argument "predictions" to `tf.math.confusion_matrix`, which should be a 1D Tensor. However, I don't see you creating it using your `test_set`.

Comment: I'll check this out thanks!